# Remove the audio narration from a PowerPoint presentation

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I recorded audio for a PowerPoint presentation and now a colleague wants me to send the presentation to him. The file is currently 18 MB and I want to get it down to handy 1 or 2MB by stripping the audio.

The only way I see is to remove the audio in the animation bar slide by slide.

Stripping notes can be done by the "inspect document" feature. But for audio I see no such way.

How can I remove the audio all at once?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is to go to the *Slide Show* menu » Record Slide Show » Clear Narrations.

Answer (score 0):

Simply click on the sound icon on your slide and press SHIFT+DELETE...     Do this for each slide

Answer (score -1):

Beside the office button,under quick access toolbar,left click the undo option.You can undo whatever actions is done,including record narration.

Comment: That will only undo the **last** action, not remove the narration from all slides.